# Would it be a bad coding style if I use ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull for general null check?

Tags: c#

I know that `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` is to ensure a function's parameter is not null, as the name `ArgumentNullException` suggests.

I found the method call is concise and easy to read.

I have a few variables that I need to check against null after assignments within my function code.

Would it be a bad coding style or against guidelines  if I use `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` to ensure general variable not null?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use it for variables, because they are not arguments. Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is a way to tell your caller that it has not provided a parameter. If that is not the situation you're in, don't use `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Don't *mislead* your colleagues: `ArgumentNullException` means that some argument (and you should provide its name) is `null` that's why your method refuses to perform the expected task. If you face an unexpected condition, `InvalidOperationException` is a possible choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the variable being checked is not an argument to the method, then it would be bad. The ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull throws an [ArgumentNullException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-7.0) which explicitly means that caller of the function did something wrong.

If the checks are for the state of the object then you are probably after an [InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=net-8.0). You might also want to consider the [ObjectNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objectnotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8.1), or create an exception type of your own.

Comment: Least surprise principle: if I've got `ArgumentNullException` then I passed `null` to the method (and `ArgumentNullException` should provide a `Name` of the incorrect argument), if problem is more compelex (unexpected `null` someweher in the method, when arguments seem to be correct one), then I want to get a different exception. +1